# Getting 400 bad request error while POSTing data with the requests module

Tags: python, python-requests

Title says everything, the strange part about it is GET requests and POST requests without data don't cause this error to occur. I'm presuming there's something wrong with the data I'm POSTing, not quite sure though. BTW, I'm using the cfscrape module (Re: https://github.com/Anorov/cloudflare-scrape) to bypass the Cloudflare DDoS protection loading page. Anyway, here's the code:

```
payload = { "username" : "testusername", "password" : "testpassword", "code" : "1111", "submit" : "Login" }
scraper = cfscrape.create_scraper()
res = scraper.post("http://www.umggaming.com/user/login", data=payload)
print res.content
```

The reponse I get while POSTing data is

```
<html>
<head><title>400 Bad Request</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>400 Bad Request</h1></center>
<hr><center>cloudflare-nginx</center>
</body>
```

As previously mentioned, other requests i.e. GET requests and POST requests containing no data respond with the html source code successfully. I'm very confused as of right now. Hopefully someone can help me out. Thank you.

@amow:

```
url = 'http://umggaming.com/user/login'
values = { 'username' : 'testusername', 'password' : 'testpassword', 'code' : '1111', 'submit' : 'Login' }
heads = { 
    'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; de; rv:1.9.2.3) Gecko/20100401 Firefox/3.6.3 (FM Scene 4.6.1)', 
    'Referer' : 'http://www.umggaming.com/user/login',
    'Cookie' : '__cfduid=EXAMPLE; cf_clearance=EXAMPLE'
}
data = urllib.urlencode(values)
req = urllib2.Request(url, headers=heads, data=data)
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
result = response.read()
print result
```

EDIT: I was able to bypass Cloudflare with the above code, but I'm not getting the expected response when sending POST requests. If an invalid username/password/code pair in submitted, the page is supposed to respond with 'Sorry your password or code is incorrect.' - I'm not getting that response. Any ideas as to why this is happening?

Comment: have you tried `"http://www.umggaming.com/user/login/"` with the forward slash at the end?

Comment: @Danoram Just tried that and still getting the same error. Also tried taking away the www with no success.

Comment: I don't think that form will allow a post from a different origin. I tried to take the raw POST from Chrome (which posts just fine) and throw it in POSTman which responds with a service unavailable 503 error.

Comment: @c1phr Hmm, anyone have any suggestions on how to get around this? Maybe grabbing a cookie with cfscrape (because mechanize doesn't include javascript support and that's what Cloudflare DDoS protection checks for) and then simulating a browser using mechanize to submit the form?

Answer (score 0):

I tested your problem using Python urllib.And I find out that:

> If you dont have a cookie of this web, it gives you a 503 code and a cookie `__cfduid`.
>
> During the 503 page ,it send a request `/cdn-cgi/l/chk_jschl?xxxxx` to get another cookie `cf_clearance`
>
> Then you can use these two cookies and a referer in your header to send the post form.

Comment: Bypassing Cloudflare isn't the issue, cfscrape already does that effectively (was able to retrieve the html with a GET request). The issue is I keep getting a 400 Bad Request error when POSTing data to /user/login

Comment: @Impelled I put the cookie in headers and get a 200 code with the post.

Comment: Still not seeing any success unfortunately... tried using urllib. Updated the post with my code.

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but since it's a top Google Search result, I'll provide what fixed it for me while trying to achieve a very similar result.

It's actually very simple : it seems like Cloudflare will not accept post requests if you haven't been "authorised" yet. Meaning you first have to make a simple `GET` request for that domain, let `cfscrape` bypass it and then you'll be able to `POST` whatever you what.

A simple fix for the above code would be :

```
payload = { "username" : "testusername", "password" : "testpassword", "code" : "1111", "submit" : "Login" }
url = "http://www.umggaming.com/user/login"

scraper = cfscrape.create_scraper()
scraper.get(url) # Make a simple GET request to bypass CloudFlare and get the authorisation cookies first
res = scraper.post("http://www.umggaming.com/user/login", data=payload)

print res.content
```